# Ontology program using rdf file in java

Tags: java

I am preparing my end of study project, but I have this problem problem is how to build an ontology using rdf file in a java program and thank you in advance

Comment: This question needs more detail.. What kind of data are you dealing with? What have you tried so far? What exactly are you unsure how to do?

Comment: OK, the first thing I thank you for your response sir, Second, I made the first interrogation step rdf file sparql it gives me a table that contains the columns that represent the triplet (s subject, object o, p predicate ), with lines that represent the results of each column (sebject, object, predicate), I still have a step tranformer of these results are classes and subclasses in ontology (owl) in java and of course thank you. I hope I managed to explain my problem.